# Side menu runs but routes file shows nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, sidebar

I am trying to make a simple side menu with chats events and settings tab. It runs if i remove the settings and events block from the routes js file but shows nothing.
Snippets are below and here is a link to the entire meteor folder to run on your comp if needed - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2MX6dSPUGBMTnMtWVVqLVcwNDQ&usp=sharing

I keep getting an error saying this:

> => Meteor server restarted
>   Started your app. App running at: http://localhost:3000/
>   Errors prevented startup: While processing files with pbastowski:angular-babel (for target web.browser):
>   client/scripts/routes.js:20:4: Babel transform error
>   Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

routes.js and settings.html respectively

```js
angular
  .module('myapp')
  .config(config);
 
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'client/templates/chats.html'
        }
      }
    });
    .state('tab.events', {
      url: '/events',
      views: {
        'tab-events': {
          templateUrl: 'client/templates/events.html'
        }
      }
    });

    .state('tab.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'tab-settings': {
          templateUrl: 'client/templates/settings.html'
        }
      }
    });


 
  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tab/recents');
}
```

```css
<!-- settings.html, events.html, chats.html are all pretty much the same -->

<ion-view view-title="Settings">
  <ion-content>
 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

menu.html

```html
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-royal">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close title="Chats" href="#/app/chats">
          Chats
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close title="Events" href="#/app/events">
          Events
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close title="Settings" href="#/app/settings">
          Settings
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you some semicolons in there that shouldn't be there. The calls to state must be nested, so don't end them with a semicolon unless it's your last one. Updated code:

```
angular
  .module('myapp')
  .config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'client/templates/chats.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.events', {
      url: '/events',
      views: {
        'tab-events': {
          templateUrl: 'client/templates/events.html'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'tab-settings': {
          templateUrl: 'client/templates/settings.html'
        }
      }
    });



  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tab/recents');
}
```